# Regex get the text before the ? but after underscore

Tags: regex

I am working on a project and I have to get a ID which is before the **?** but after **underscore**. I have to match the ID which has alphabets and numbers.

I tried `^(.+?)\?` but it matches all texts after **?**

The link is like this: http://localhost/id=some_thing_Id0ID0Id?something=lorem

How can I do this?

Comment: Try [`_([^_?]+)\?`](https://regex101.com/r/JghRA9/1). Is the `?` always present? If not, `_([^_?]+)(?:\?|$)` might be a better option. What is the language you are coding it in?

Comment: is the Id is going to start with `Id` always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `^(.+?)\?` pattern matches any 1 or more chars up to the first (leftmost) occurrence of the `?` char from the start of the string.

You seem to want to get the last alphanumeric part from the last `_` up to the `?` char.

You may capture that substring with

```
_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\?
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQcJPP/3).

However, you might want to allow matching even if the substring you want to get is at the end of string (if there is no `?`). Then you may use

```
_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\?|$)
```

The `(?:\?|$)` part matches a `?` (with `\?`) or (`|`) end of string (`$`). See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQcJPP/2).

If there can be more than just numbers and letters, you may use a more generic solution that captures any chars but `?` and `_`:

```
_([^_?]+)(?:\?|$)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQcJPP/1).

Comment: Thanks, the first one was what I needed. Also, thanks for suggesting other matches.